# How to get last N records with activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

With `:limit` in query, I will get first N records. What is the easiest way to get last N records?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

### Updated Answer (2020)

You can get last N records simply by using [last](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/last) method:

`Record.last(N)`

Example:

`User.last(5)`

Returns 5 users in descending order by their id.

### Deprecated (Old Answer)

An active record query like this I think would get you what you want ('Something' is the model name):

```
Something.find(:all, :order => "id desc", :limit => 5).reverse
```

**edit**: As noted in the comments, another way:

```
result = Something.find(:all, :order => "id desc", :limit => 5)

while !result.empty?
        puts result.pop
end
```

Comment: seems unnecessary to order the data twice, I'm currently getting the count first and using it with offset

Comment: That was the other method I was thinking of, but that seems like even more work since that's 2 queries against the database instead of 1. I guess I assume that you need to iterate over the array at some point, so you could let ruby sort it at at that time. (ie. records.reverse.each do ..)

Comment: Alternately, you could not reverse the array and use Array.pop to iterate over the array rather than reversing it.. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000280

Comment: For Rails 3, see Bongs' reply instead.  This way still works, but is no longer the preferred way.

Comment: Calling #find(:all) is deprecated. Call #all directly instead.

Comment: This method is deprecated. Use `Something.last(n)` instead.

Answer (score 284):

This is the Rails 3 way

```
SomeModel.last(5) # last 5 records in ascending order

SomeModel.last(5).reverse # last 5 records in descending order
```

Comment: Try this with Postgres! I've certainly had trouble with first. In SQL the order isn't guaranteed unless you specify it, but MySQL is more forgiving.

Comment: Note: this is not a good way of implementing it, performance-wise - at least not up to Rails 3.1.

SomeModel.last(5) will execute the select statement without a limit, returning all records of SomeModel to Ruby as an array, after which Ruby will pick out the last (5) elements. Efficiency-wise, currently, you want to use limit - particularly if you have potentially many elements.

Comment: It does exactly what it should: `SELECT "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50`

Comment: In Rails 4 the query generated by .last() is also optimal as Nick mentioned

Comment: Note: OK for full records (as asked), but note that if you need only some columns, you should use pluck(:my_col1, :my_col2, ...). If you need many rows and few columns of data at the end of a big table, last + map is inefficient (it creates full valid records first), limit + pluck is efficient (it is handled by DB).

Comment: This is incorrect for Rails 4+, since `SomeModel.last(5).class` == `Array`. The correct approach is `SomeModel.limit(5).order('id desc')` per Arthur Neves, which results in `SELECT  \"somemodels\".* FROM \"somemodels\" ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 55):

new way to do it in rails 3.1 is `SomeModel.limit(5).order('id desc')`

Comment: This is better than `last(5)` because it returns a scope for further chaining.

Comment: I use `SomeModel.limit(100).reverse_order` on Rails 4 (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#reverse-order) It's the same.

Comment: Example of "scope for further chaining" mentioned by @lulalala: If you only need one column, `SomeModel.limit(5).order('id desc').pluck(:col)` will do `SELECT SomeModel.col FROM SomeModel ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 5` which is much more efficient than grabbing all columns and discarding all but one column with `SomeModel.last(5).map(&:col) ` which does `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT col` (you can't pluck after calling last; lazy-eval chain ends with last).

Answer (score 53):

## For Rails 5 (and likely Rails 4)

#### Bad:

```
Something.last(5)
```

because:

```
Something.last(5).class
=> Array
```

so:

```
Something.last(50000).count
```

will likely blow up your memory or take forever.

#### Good approach:

```
Something.limit(5).order('id desc')
```

because:

```
Something.limit(5).order('id desc').class
=> Image::ActiveRecord_Relation

Something.limit(5).order('id desc').to_sql
=> "SELECT  \"somethings\".* FROM \"somethings\" ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 5"
```

The latter is an unevaluated scope. You can chain it, or convert it to an array via `.to_a`. So:

```
Something.limit(50000).order('id desc').count
```

... takes a second.

Comment: And even Rails 3, actually. ;)

Answer (score 34):

For **Rails 4 and above version:**

You can try something like this If you want **first oldest entry**

```
YourModel.order(id: :asc).limit(5).each do |d|
```

---

You can try something like this if you want **last latest entries**..

```
YourModel.order(id: :desc).limit(5).each do |d|
```

Comment: This looks like more up to date answer for Rails 4 than the accepted one. I think that most recent syntax should look like this: `YourModel.all.order(id: :desc).limit(5)`

Comment: @user2041318 : thanks for this new syntax without `" "`

Comment: Order() returns all the records. There is no need to chain `YourModel.all.order()` because is the same as `YourModel.order()`

Answer (score 26):

Solution is here:

```
SomeModel.last(5).reverse
```

Since rails is lazy, it will eventually hit the database with SQL like: "SELECT  `table`.* FROM `table`  ORDER BY `table`.`id` DESC LIMIT 5".

Comment: this would load all records of `SomeModel`

Comment: A better approach would be to limit(); this doesn't look efficient.

Comment: @Developer is absolutely right.  The SQL executed was: `SELECT  `table`.* FROM `table`  ORDER BY `table`.`id` DESC LIMIT 5`

it does **not** perform a select all

Answer (score 4):

If you need to set some ordering on results then use:

```
Model.order('name desc').limit(n) # n= number
```

if you do not need any ordering, and just need records saved in the table then use:

```
Model.last(n) # n= any number
```

Answer (score 4):

Just try:

```
Model.order("field_for_sort desc").limit(5)
```

Comment: You should explain why this solution is viable.

Answer (score 4):

In my rails `(rails 4.2)` project, I use

```
Model.last(10) # get the last 10 record order by id
```

and it works.

Answer (score 3):

we can use `Model.last(5)` or `Model.limit(5).order(id: :desc)` in rails 5.2

Answer (score 1):

I find that this query is better/faster for using the "pluck" method, which I love:

```
Challenge.limit(5).order('id desc')
```

This gives an ActiveRecord as the output; so you can use .pluck on it like this:

```
Challenge.limit(5).order('id desc').pluck(:id)
```

which quickly gives the ids as an array while using optimal SQL code.

Comment: `Challenge.limit(5).order('id desc').ids` will work just as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say N = 5 and your model is `Message`, you can do something like this:

```ruby
Message.order(id: :asc).from(Message.all.order(id: :desc).limit(5), :messages)
```

Look at the sql:

```sql
SELECT "messages".* FROM (
  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages"  ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 5
) messages  ORDER BY "messages"."created_at" ASC
```

The key is the subselect. First we need to define what are the last messages we want and then we have to order them in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default scope in your model that specifies an ascending order in Rails 3 you'll need to use reorder rather than order as specified by Arthur Neves above:

```
Something.limit(5).reorder('id desc')
```

or

```
Something.reorder('id desc').limit(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be:

```
Model.limit(5).order(id: :desc)
```

There is a problem with this solution, as `id` can't be the sole determiner of when a record was created in the time.

A more reliable solution would be:

```
Model.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
```

As others have pointed out, one can also use `Model.last(5)`. The only gotcha with this is that it returns `Array`, and not `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

Answer (score -5):

Add an :order parameter to the query