# how to fetch most recent records from db in ruby on rails and where to write this query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to fetch 5 most recent artilce's titles from my db in ruby on rails. I have already fetched( fetch all article' title)  article's title but those are  not restricted by this (5 most recent) condition. Where to write to this logic, either in controller or in model part. If it should be written in model then how to access it in views part. Whether it will be written in controller part. Please suggest me.

article model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :body
   attr_accessible :tag_list
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :tags, through: :taggings
   validates :title, :body, :tag_list,  :presence => true



   def tag_list
    self.tags.collect do |tag|
     tag.name
    end.join(", ")
   end

   def tag_list=(tags_string)
    tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
    new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name) }
    self.tags = new_or_found_tags
   end
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_user_admin, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]

    def is_user_admin
      redirect_to(action: :index) unless current_user.try(:is_admin?) 
      return false 
    end
      def index
          @articles = Article.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
      end
    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
      def new
      @article = Article.new
      end
    def create
      @article = Article.new(params[:article])
      @article.user_id = current_user.id
      if @article.save
        flash[:success] = "article created!"
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
      else
        render 'new' 
      end 
    end
    def destroy
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @article.destroy
      redirect_to action:  'index'  
    end
    def edit
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
    def update
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
       flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
       redirect_to article_path(@article)
      else 
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
end
```

article/index.rb

```
   <div style="background-color:#1fb2e8; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 1.6em"> recent article </div>
          <div style="font-size: 1.3em">
           <% @articles.each do |article| %>
            <div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:8px">  <%= link_to article.title.first(5), article_path(article) %></div>
           <% end %>
```

I tried to fetch using first or last(5), but did not worked. How to get 5 or 10 recent titles. Please suggest me.

Comment: Seems to me that this duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420352/how-to-get-last-n-records-with-activerecord

Comment: hi Guedes, but my doubt is that where to write this logic and how to access this in views.

Comment: `@article_titles = Article.select(:title).last(10)` in controller action and then use `@article_titles` in view.

Comment: hi Mike, your suggestion worked fine. Thanks. but now i got routing error "Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>#<Article title: "Convention over Configuration (CoC): ">}". I have implemented like this <% @article_titles.each do |article_title | %>
            <div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:8px">  <%= link_to article_title.title, article_path(article_title) %></div>
            <% end %>. It may be that i have not implemented it well . Please look at my code and error message.

Answer (score 2):

A scope might be a nice way to do this

```
scope :most_recent, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 5
```

[Rails 3.2 Scope Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scope)

Answer (score 0):

hello write this logic in model

please refer following links

[Find the newest record in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870531/find-the-newest-record-in-rails-3)

Comment: The best practise is to write the Logic in Model.