# Whats the best way to get the nth to last record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I saw here: [How to get last N records with activerecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420352/how-to-get-last-n-records-with-activerecord) that the best way to get the last 5 records is SomeModel.last(5).
Is the best way to get the 5th last record only SomeModel.last(5).first or is it something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a combination of `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, and ensuring that the query is using `ORDER BY` as a constraint. This is described on the PostgreSQL - [Queries: Limit and Offset documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/queries-limit.html).

An example is:

```
irb> SomeModel.count
=> 35

irb> SomeModel.order(:id).reverse_order.limit(1).offset(4)
# SomeModel Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "some_models".* FROM "some_models" ORDER BY "some_models".id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SomeModel id: 31, name: "hello world", created_at: "2014-03-24 21:52:46", updated_at: "2014-03-24 21:52:46">]>
```

Which yields the same result (albeit as an AR::Relation) as:

```
irb> SomeModels.last(5).first
# SELECT "some_models".* FROM "some_models" ORDER BY "some_models"."id" DESC LIMIT 5
=> #<SomeModel id: 31, name: "hello world", created_at: "2014-03-24 21:52:46", updated_at: "2014-03-24 21:52:46">
```

The difference is that in the former query, PostgreSQL will treat the `.reverse_order.limit.offset` query in memory, and restrict the values appropriately before it returns the result. In the latter, PostgreSQL will return 5 results, and you restrict the values in Ruby by using `#first`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`offset`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset) with a query in the reverse order. For example, the fifth last created record can be retrieved with:

```
SomeModel.order("created_at DESC").offset(4).first
```

Comment: This is not getting me the same element: `User.count #=> 11`, `User.order('created_at DESC').offset(5).first.id #=> 6` and `User.last(5).first.id #=> 7`. Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: No you're doing it right @raviolicode `use offset to specify the number of records to skip before starting to return the records`. It will skip the last 5 records, it should actually be `offset(4)`

Comment: @liamneesonsarmsauce, raviolicode: Thanks, I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the 5th last record is with combination of descending sort, and [fifth](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-fifth):

```
SomeModel.order("created_at DESC").fifth
```