# generic way of testing order by clause in rails using minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a default scope in a model defined as follows:

`default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }`

and a test defined as follows:

```
class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @first_item = items(:one)
    @second_item = items(:two)
    @third_item = items(:three)
    @fourth_item = items(:four)
  end

  test "items should be ordered by time they got created ( default scope)" do
    assert_equal [@fourth_item,@third_item, @second_item, @first_item], Item.all
  end
```

and  fixtures:

```
one:
  created_at: 2017-06-06 00:00:00 -0700

two:
  created_at: 2017-06-06 00:00:02 -0700

three:
  created_at: 2017-06-06 00:00:09 -0700

four:
  created_at: 2017-06-06 00:00:30 -0700
```

test **passes** however , **everytime I add a new fixture to the above fixture file , the test fails** and  I have to add that new item to the array in `assert_equals` statement.

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030727/1340281) which seems very generic but test still passes when its suppose to fail

```
items = Items.first(3) # and items.first(3).reverse still passes as well :(
assert_equals [items[0], items[1], items[2]], items
```

but unfortunately , the test passes even when I change the order to `ASC` where it suppose to be failing.

**is there a generic way of testing a specific number of items order ?**

I use **minitest**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is to check if your array of objects are ordered by the given attribute or not. Use each_cons that allows you to enumerate on the array with n consecutive elements at a time. [each_cons doc](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons)

```
assert (Item.all.each_cons(2).all?{|a,b| a.created_at >= b.created_at})
```